# How to store the output of the Stat_smooth or geom_smooth as a data file?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, plotly, smoothing

I am developing a shiny app, in which I am generating various scatter plots by uploading the datasets. I am also using `stat_smooth` on the generated scatter plots. Now, I want to be able to store the generated `stat_smooth` profile as a dataset. How can I do that?

Further, I want to compile various stat_smooth profiles in one graph, that's why I want to store those as a dataset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ggplot_build`. Here is an example:

```
library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(data = mtcars) +
  geom_point(aes(hp, mpg)) +
  stat_smooth(aes(hp, mpg))

p2 <- ggplot_build(p)

head(p2$data[[2]])
```

**Output**

```
    x        y     ymin     ymax       se PANEL group  colour   fill
1 52.00000 31.15895 27.03176 35.28614 2.009302     1    -1 #3366FF grey60
2 55.58228 30.51224 26.91154 34.11295 1.752985     1    -1 #3366FF grey60
3 59.16456 29.87138 26.72390 33.01886 1.532336     1    -1 #3366FF grey60
4 62.74684 29.23738 26.46507 32.00968 1.349680     1    -1 #3366FF grey60
5 66.32911 28.61085 26.13527 31.08643 1.205223     1    -1 #3366FF grey60
6 69.91139 27.99200 25.73825 30.24575 1.097226     1    -1 #3366FF grey60
  size linetype weight alpha
1    1        1      1   0.4
2    1        1      1   0.4
3    1        1      1   0.4
4    1        1      1   0.4
5    1        1      1   0.4
6    1        1      1   0.4
```

Comment: Can we define the number of datapoints which will get extracted from the fit generated by stat_smooth or geom_smooth? In my case, I am able to extract those datapoints, but 100 points are getting extracted, I need more in some cases? Is it possible to define the number points that will get extracted from the fitted plot?